# node_module folder's react folder doesn't contain useMemo, useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, version, node-modules

Hi I was using the below code in a typescript file,

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
...
function useBLE(): BluetoothLowEnergyApi {
  
  const bleManager = useMemo(() => new BleManager(), []);
  const [allDevices, setAllDevices] = useState<Device[]>([]);
...
}
...
```

but vs code gives an error like -> `Module '"react"' has no exported member 'useMemo', 'useState'`
I checked the node_module folder's react folder and it doesn't contain useMemo, useState hooks. How can I solve this issue :( My node version is v16.14.0

Comment: What version of react are you using?